# Where is the extra space coming from in my h1 elements?

Tags: html, css, tags

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out where the extra space is coming from in my h1 tag. I have reset the CSS padding and margin to 0, and set the line-height the same as the font size, and i expect the text to have no space above or below, within the tag, and to be vertically centered (redundant, but at least vertically centered with minimal space above and below.... a few pixels at most).

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance for any help anyone can offer.

```css
h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #FC9;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 3em;
}
```

```html
<h1>THIS IS A TEST</h1>
```

Comment: Remove line-height: 3em; from this class .lineheighttest{}

Answer (score 0):

The space is appearing from this rule of css:

```
.lineheighttest {
    line-height:3em;
}
```

If you want to put that rule then may be you want to set negative margin on spacer.

Answer (score 0):

you have placed the css for class **lineheighttest** to set the **line height 3em**.Remove that then it will be working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Explanation:

When you set the font-size to font-size:3em; you set it to 3x the size of the body font size.

When you set the line height to 3em for the H1 line, you are setting it to 3x the font size.

```css
h1 {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 background-color:#FC9;
 font-size:3em;
text-transform:uppercase;
font-family: 'Khula', sans-serif;
font-weight:300;
vertical-align:middle;
}

.lineheighttest {
    line-height:.75em;
    padding-top:2px;
}

.spacer {
    height:30px;
    background-color:#6BC7D0;
}
```

```html
<h1>THIS IS A TEST</h1>

<div class="spacer"></div>

<h1 class="lineheighttest" >THIS IS A TEST</h1>
```

Comment: HI Lance, thanks so much for responding. OK, so i see my confusion with the ems and the line-heights... to an extent. Thank you! However, how do i get it so there is no space above or below my h1 against it's background—or to be centered vertically. in your example, the h1 still seems to have a margin at the bottom, rather than being centered.

EDIT: so i tried 48px for the .lineheighttest line height, which is the same as 1em, and yes, there is the remaining margin under the header still. (stating the obvious, but just wanted to explain that i understood what you explained, and tested it)

Comment: Hmmm, what browser are you using?  To me in IE, it does look centered vertically.

Comment: Okay, I see it. There is slightly more on the bottom.  Try setting your line-height to .75em and see if that gets it close enough for you.

Comment: And also add padding-top:2px to it.  I edited my answer.  Rerun the code snippet and look at the bottom one.

Comment: I see. Thanks! So is the only way to achieve this with adding padding and fiddling with the height? There is no set rule that would work in css universally? (is this a Firefox issue then?)

Comment: I'm using IE and Chrome and they are behaving the same.